# Toolbar and TabLayout don't hide when I scroll the RecyclerView up

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-tablayout

I am having trouble getting the `Toolbar` and `TabLayout` to hide when I scroll up. I have 3 different xml files: 1) `Toolbar`, 2) `TabLayoutFragment` (here I have the `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`, and I **include** the `toolbar` here, and 3) `HomeFragment` (contains the `RecyclerView`). I need for the `Toolbar` to hide when I scroll up, and I have seen in many other posts that most people use a `CoordinatorLayout` instead of a `Relative Layout` or `Linear Layout`, and then they have to add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` which I have done, but I still can't get the `Toolbar` to hide when scrolling the `RecyclerView` up.

I've also added this to the `RecyclerView`, but still nothing... `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Could someone point out what is missing here?

**Toolbar**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_events"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_home_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/scriptbl"
                    android:text="Events"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="60sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    style="@style/SelectableIconThemeBackground"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/camera"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_search" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/filter"
                    style="@style/SelectableIconThemeBackground"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/search"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/camera"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon10_sort" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/options"
                    style="@style/SelectableIconThemeBackground"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/options"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_short_text" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**TabLayoutFragment**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_home_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="Home"
    tools:context=".Fragment.TabLayoutFragment">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_events"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_events" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#000"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
        app:tabRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorBlack" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**HomeFragment**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="fragment_home"
    tools:context=".Fragment.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Welcome to Events!"
                android:textColor="#d9d9d9"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/location"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/icon_loc" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/location"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_following"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: app:layout_behavior needs Coordinator layout as parent in which containing your Toolbar then only your Toolbar will understand that for which layout scrolling it needs to hide.

Comment: @SophiaGray okay, so sI made it's parent layout a coordinatorLayout… Everything else should be good as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it programmatically by adding the `addOnScrollListener` method.

On the `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` method hide the toolbar and TabLayout and on `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` method you can show it again if you want to show them again.

You can try it in such way:

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        // Show your view again.. If you want to show them..
    } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
        // Hide your view..
    }

    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

}});
```

Or You can use recycler view's `addOnScrollListener` method:

Refer: [addOnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener#onScrolled(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,%20int,%20int))

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    if (dy > 0) {
        //Scrolling down
        // Show your controllers from here
    } else if (dy < 0) {
        //Scrolling up
        // Hide your controllers from here
    }
}});
```

Also, you can add some animations there to show and hide your toolbar and tab layouts.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Should I do this in my TabLayoutFragment? I'm assuming...

Comment: You can take an instance of your Parent Activity and make it using like this:  MainActivity.getInstance().TabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Okay, I did this, but it works strangely. It doesn't look appealing when you scroll the ```TabLayout``` disappears, and then when it's idle it reappears. It doesn't look appealing at all. Is there another "state" that it disappears when scrolling up and reappears when scrolling down?

Comment: For the scroll up and scroll down events you can check this also: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener#onScrolled(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,%20int,%20int)                                                                                                                                      or consider the example in the next comment.

Comment: recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (dy > 0) {
            //Scrolling down
        } else if (dy < 0) {
            //Scrolling up
        }
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Place the toolbar and the tablayout within the ScrollView group to get the scrolling part.

```
<ScrollView>
   <Toolbar></Toolbar>
   <Tablayout></Tablayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Should I change my LinearLayout in TabLayoutFragment to ScrollView?